# Adding prefix '>' from my array tree

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, tree, treeview

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 39
        [parent_id] => 0
        [sku] => Parent
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40
        [parent_id] => 39
        [sku] => Child of parent id 39
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [parent_id] => 40
        [sku] => Child of child id 40
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 42
        [parent_id] => 40
        [sku] => Another child of child id 40
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 43
        [parent_id] => 39
        [sku] => Another child of parent id 39
    )
etc..
)
```

I have here an associative arrays which basically is a parent - child relationship. There's been so many sample in the web on how to build a tree that help me a lot. But right now I just want to format my array to something like this:

```
> Parent                               --> first prefix ">"
    >> Child of parent id 39           --> added two ">" prefixes
        >>> Child of child id 40       --> added three ">" prefixes
        >>> Another child of child id 40
    >> Another child of parent id 39
and so on..
```

Update:
This is how I build my tree for now:

```
function pdf_content($data, $parentId = 0)
{
    $str = '';

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $str .= '<li>';
            $str .= $row['sku'];
            $str .= pdf_content($data, $row['id']);
            $str .= '</li>';
        }
    }

    if ($str) {
        $str = "<ol class='dashed'>" . $str . '</ol>';
    }
    return $str;
}
// this is using the ol list style.
```

So first the children will have to get its parent and append the prefix ">".I already have a code to build a tree but formatting it to something like this got me stuck on a tree.

Comment: Can you update the question with how are you building the tree?

Comment: hi @Dwijen, please see my updated post.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, i already have a buildTree function. My problem is the way I want the result to display using prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
function pdf_content($items, $parentId = 0, $prefix = '>')
{
    $str = '';
    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
       if ($item['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
           $str .= '<li>';
           $str .= $prefix.$item['sku'];
           $str .= pdf_content($items, $item['id'], $prefix.'>');
           $str .= '</li>';
       }
    }
    if ($str) {
        $str = "<ol class='dashed'>" . $str . '</ol>';
    }
    return $str;
}

$string = pdf_content($array);
```

This is what I get as the Output -

```
>Parent
    >>Parent 39
        >>>Parent 40
        >>>Parent 40
    >>Parent 39
```

Answer (score 1):

To adding Prefix use recursive function with pass parameter `$prefix = '>'` if child found then concatinate `$prefix .=  '>'` and pass in your Function if child not found then overwrite to `$prefix = '>'` only

Comment: hi could you see my updated post. I added my function for build a tree. Maybe you could help me out..

Comment: hello, please see link to make tree i always use this for making tree categories http://leon.vankammen.eu/tech/storing-retrieving-hierarchical-trees-between-php-and-mysql.html